# read/load parts of the irregular file by Matlab

Tags: matlab, readfile

I would like to partly load a PTX file by matlab (please see the following example)

I need to read and write the first two row (2 numbers) into 2 variables say a and b. And read and write the data from 5th row to the end into a matrix

Thanks for your help

```
114
221
1 0 0
1 0 0 0 
-5.566405 -7.161944 -1.144557 0.197208 24 29 35
-5.560656 -7.154540 -1.137673 0.222400 29 32 39
-5.559846 -7.153491 -1.131895 0.254002 37 40 49
-5.560894 -7.154833 -1.126452 0.305013 51 54 63
-5.560084 -7.153783 -1.120633 0.290013 72 76 88
-5.561128 -7.155119 -1.115189 0.243214 105 113 134
-5.563203 -7.157782 -1.109926 0.227604 130 143 177
-5.569191 -7.165479 -1.105504 0.201602 121 140 173
-7.833616 -10.078705 -1.546952 0.130007 94 112 134
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [tdfread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tdfread.html) function in order to get the data into Matlab. It should be something like `datafile = tdfread(filename, '\t')`. Once you have that, index into the variable returned from that function like

```
a = datafile(1, 1);
b = datafile(2, 1);
data = datafile(5:end, :);
```